# When should we use a Backbone JS collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Does anyone know some good use cases of a Backbone collection? Thanks.

Comment: question should not be down voted if anyone  not getting it :)

Comment: true, however this is not a question with a clear definable answer, so it might just be in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3):

Good question,
Models and Collections are used for organizing data in the web application. Collection is just a collection of a models.

**Answer:**
For example, If a book is a model, Library can be a collection, if photo is a model, Album can be a collection.

Basically, Backbone.js can be used to design one page javascript web application. The answer to your question is you can collect, add, delete, sort 
with the help of collection.

**Model:** This defines the actural structure of a unit, called as model. 
**Collections:** Collection is used to collect and perform aggregate operations over the all models.